# Is it necessary to have only recommendations from Computer Science professors for an application to Computer Science grad program?

Tags: graduate-admissions, application

Can I also have my finance/economics professor recommend me? I have a good relationship with her. Would it matter if she isn't from the CS department in my college?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, absolutely.  Your references should be people who know you, your work and your capabilities best and can give the admissions committee the best possible insight into what to expect from you.  That matters a lot more than what department they're in.  For that matter, they don't even have to be former instructors.  You might also turn to a former supervisor at an internship you did one summer if the work you did for them was especially impressive.

Comment: So the fact my professor is from a non CS department wouldn't lessen the impact/importance of the recommendations? right?

Comment: I actually figured a little problem with the way my question is phrased. I meant to ask, does the recommender SOLELY has to be a CS prof or that won't really matter. Apologise for the poorly formed question.

Comment: If you're applying to a graduate program in CS, you'll probably want at least one and hopefully two of the three references you'll likely need from people who can speak to your potential as a computer scientist.  But they definitely don't all have to be CS instructors.  Given the choice between a reference from a CS instructor who only knows you as a name on his roster of 250 students in his lecture versus a finance instructor who knows you and your work really well, go with the latter.  A reference that can only report your grade is not very helpful; they'll already have your transcript.

Comment: That is exactly what I wanted to clear! Thanks a lot for responding :D

Answer (score 2):

I think that Nicole’s [answer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/100242/83038) hits the main point, but there’s a second question lurking here: does a letter of recommendation from a CS professor carry more weight than a similar one from a non-CS professor.

The purpose of letters of recommendation is to testify to your **known or expected ability to do computer science research.** A CS professor will be intrinsically trusted more than a non-CS professor, and amongst non-CS professors those who have experience with CS work or those who work in CS-related fields will carry more weight than those who don’t. For example, a quantum computation researcher who is in the chem department will count for more than most other kinds of chemistry professors.

**This should not be taken to disagree with anything in Nicole’s answer.** If you barely know a prof or didn’t do research with them, it’s far far harder for them to vouch for your skills as a researcher at all than if they did do research with you. All research experiences you have will be - to some extent - relevant and it’s definitely worth seeking out professors from any department that can speak strongly and in detail about you and your prowess.

Comment: Having served on graduate admissions committees, I think you're wrong and I suspect it reflects lack of experience.  The most useful LORs are from people who know a candidate well and can speak to the individual's critical thinking skills, ability to deal with abstract concepts and new material, problem-solving skills, creativity, dedication, attitude, etc.  That absolutely does not have to be a professor in CS just because the student is applying in CS.  A CS professor who only knows the student's grade is a worthless reference.

Comment: @NicoleHamilton I think I miss-represented my ideas then. The OP is asking if a letter of recommendation is less Impactful if it comes from a non-CS person. I have been told time and time again by people who have served on committees that the answer is yes. That definitely doesn’t mean it’s not impactful, and that definitely doesn’t mean you should only ask CS people. But given two identical letters, one from an Econ professor and one from a CS professor, the later will carry more weight. Do you disagree with that assertion?

Comment: @Nicole Rereading my answer, I think it’s more accurate to say I wildly misrepresented myself. I’ve substantially edited my answer to try to articulate the intended point.

Comment: This is an improvement.  I'll undo my downvote.